# Changing the image width and height

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I would like to change the height and width of the image. Displays the image using the `canvas`:

```
canvas.drawBitmap (_image, 0, 0, null);
```

How to change the size of the bitmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Matrix:

```
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();

float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;      

matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
                    width, height, matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...)`